# Rate of Change Calculus question for a sphere.

Tags: calculus

I am having a problem getting started on this problem.

Rate of inflation of a balloon. A spherical balloon is inflated at a rate of 10 cubic cm/min. At what rate is the diameter of the balloon increasing when the balloon has a diameter of 5 cm.

For the life of me I cannot figure out what formula to begin with so I can find dd/dt (this is an assumption that it is related to diameter) not sure it could be related to anything else. I am not looking for the problem to be solved just help getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: volume of the balloon($V$) = $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi {(\frac{D}{2})}^3=\frac{1}{6}\pi D^3$

and you are given $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and need to find $\frac{dD}{dt}$

Comment: thank you yes this helped.

Comment: @samack:i am glad :)

Answer (score 0):

We need a relationship between the diameter $x$ and the volume $V$. The standard formula for volume is 
$$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3,$$
where $r$ is the radius.
In terms of diameter, since $r=x/2$, we have
$$V=\frac{\pi x^3}{6}.$$
It is I think best to differentiate immediately, using the Chain Rule.
We get
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{\pi x^2}{2}\frac{dx}{dt}.$$
Now can you finish?